# Jury-rig second monitor on school lectern?

Tags: video, multiple-monitors

I teach at a community college, lecturing daily with slideshow presentations (which mostly originate from the textbook publisher). The classrooms where I teach have a lectern computer with an overhead projector.

Unfortunately, the lectern computers were all installed in a way that they only have a single video output, and the projector can only show a duplicate of what's on the lectern monitor itself. (My understanding is that a cheap video splitter was used instead of two separate monitor outputs.) Therefore, it's impossible to make use of the standard slideshow-presentation "presenter view" feature (where the audience sees one thing on the projector, while the presenter sees notes, upcoming slides, timer, etc. on the lectern monitor).

I've inquired about getting this fixed numerous times, going back over a decade now. I'm possibly the only person in my department who uses presentation slides -- it's still considered novel and unusual -- and I don't think anyone I've ever spoken to understands what the issue or "presenter view" is. So, I see no sign that the hardware issue will be fixed.

Thus, I'm looking for some way that I might be able to jury-rig an effective second monitor temporarily while I'm class. I have access to the computer tower under the lectern, and can plug in USB devices as needed (routinely use a memory stick, digital clicker, etc.). I don't have access to the monitor cables (padlocked at the back of the PC tower). I have my own tablet, laptop, etc. that I could bring and plug in. The school towers all run Windows. The lecterns have MS Powerpoint locally installed; but I normally I run slideshows via Libre Office Portable Impress from a USB stick. The lecterns do not have the Miracast wi-fi screen-casting software available.

At this point, I'm personally stumped. What options are there for me to plug in another device here, and get the functionality of the slideshow "presenter view", with different image on instructor monitor vs. overhead projector display?

**Update**: It turns out that the "cheap video splitter" story that I'd been told by IT staff was not actually correct (nor something I could verify, the way the towers are locked in place with the back inaccessible). The selected answer shows how to access the existing projector as an extended monitor in Windows, which apparently no one at my institution knew to explain.

Comment: have you considered bribing the IT people? Also what interfaces do they use? Can you plug unto the *projector* and what interfaces do they have?

Comment: Could you print out the extra information instead?

Comment: The projector's installed up on the ceiling near the back of the room and so not accessible that way.

Comment: @EugeneStyer: I've done that, and even wrote a small app for that workflow, but I've found it to be very inconvenient to carry & manage the paper notes separately throughout every presentation. (https://github.com/danielrcollins1/ImpressExtractNotes)

Comment: @EugeneStyer Print? This is 2023!

Comment: There exists a [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.libreoffice.impressremote) that can act as a remote to LibreOffice Impress, while showing notes on the phone screen. Might have some firewall trouble setting it up, though.

Comment: @jpa: I looked at that previously, but I think it needs wi-fi which the lectern PC doesn't have?

Comment: The turn of phrase in this industry is "confidence monitor". You want the confidence monitor to show your notes. That might help you get the answer from IT on how to do this. Technically, it's pretty easy to accomplish, unless there is a long distance between computer and the video splitter. That would require a new wire run. If that has to go in wall, then it's a non-starter. IT will not help in that situation.

Comment: Can't you just put your notes on some paper? Maybe learn to depend on them less? I now that doesn't solve your technical question, but it will probably improve your presenting skills. IMO, the best presenters do not use notes, because they are very familiar with their topic and sometimes individual presentations.

Comment: @user287352: Paper notes were addressed in comments above.

Comment: Which version of what operating system do your lectern computers use?

A projector showing only a duplicate of the lectern monitor sounds quite normal but where does 'installed (with only) a single video output' come from, please?

If the machines have only a single video output, that's all but 'installed in a way' suggests there is more than one output and the operating system is limiting the options.

If you've been inquiring for a decade, why not complain to senior management? By the same token how, this century, can you be the only one using presentation slides?

Comment: Many of these answers and comments address hardware, plugs splitters and wiring, as well as software solutions.   What's missing is the meatware answers, or addressing the mindset and culture of the site, and how other users cope with change.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: Generally such apps expect the other device to be on the same IP network (and usually the same subnet, so that auto discovery would work). *How* the desktop PC is connected to the network rarely matters at all, as the same subnet can easily extend across both WiFi and Ethernet (just as it almost always does on home routers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the lectern computers were all installed in a way that they only have a single video output, and the projector can only show a duplicate of what's on the lectern monitor itself. (My understanding is that a cheap video splitter was used instead of two separate monitor outputs.)

While a cheap video splitter is likely, that's not the only possibility – in many cases, even if two independent outputs are available they will be deliberately set to "Duplicate" mode to retain user familiarity.

Before purchasing anything, go to Settings→Display and check whether it has detected two displays or just one; if there are two – hit <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on the lectern computer to check whether the "Extend" mode works.

> What options are there for me to plug in another device here,

Bring your laptop and a HDMI capture card. Connect the capture card via HDMI to your laptop's output and via USB to the PC tower. Run something like a portable version of OBS to display the capture card's input in full screen.

I have no idea what sort of quality you'd get from a USB connected capture card (especially if the available ports aren't even USB 3.x), but for slide shows it should work.

Comment: You don't even need OBS - the built in camera app works. I tend to buy the cheap models (5-20 USD) and the quality is passable.  If I understand correctly - you're using the laptop as a *primary* and the lectern PC as a output for that?

Comment: Yes, the opposite of the DisplayLink suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, testing this setup at home: The laptop HDMI output doesn't count as a second monitor (just duplicates laptop screen), so Libre Office is still unable to engage presenter view.

Comment: @Daniel: I've never seen a laptop where it wouldn't count as a second independent output. (Even the integrated GPUs already have it separate, so it would take *effort* from the manufacturer to disregard that and add a splitter just to get less functionality for more cost.) If it's not a matter of selecting the right mode under Win+P, then it's probably a driver issue. (But in the most unlikely case that it's really hard-duplicated, you can combine this method with a DisplayLink USB video output...)

Comment: Good USB capture cards are at least $400. Then there's the software you'll use with it... OBS is free, though, I've never used it. Some people swear by it, but they've never used the real stuff.

Comment: Got this working at home now -- I had no awareness of the Win+P project settings until you mentioned it here (now set to Extend). Using the built-in Windows Camera app on the receiving machine seems the most elegant. I'll test this on the school computer and if that works then I'll likely accept this answer.

Comment: @Daniel: Then maybe you actually have the same option on the school computer and just never have tried it? Many such PCs just have both outputs set to "Duplicate" to make things easier for teachers who want to demonstrate things other than Powerpoint slides (and can't remember the mode-switch key for longer than a week).

Comment: @u1686_grawity: Agreed, I put that on my to-try list earlier tonight.

Comment: Indeed, it turns out that the Win+P projector settings does get a working second monitor state on the school computer (and hence the slideshow presenter view function). Maybe embarrassing for me -- but none of the IT staff or even the head of IT ever knew to tell me that when I asked. In addition, the laptop output strategy also works and would have been my backup plan. Thanks for this answer (and the edit after comments).

Comment: @Daniel: I'd say this is partially an Impress thing as well – I faintly remember that MS PowerPoint (2016, at least) has the ability to bypass the desktop mirroring and show a presenter view even if the desktop is normally in "Duplicate" mode (I assume it temporarily switches to Extend or something like that).

Comment: I _thought_ that I'd tried PowerPoint on the school lectern in the past with the same negative result -- but it was a while ago and my memory may be hazy. Thanks again.

Comment: Here's one last thing you might clarify to further improve this insightful answer -- The current Windows interface for Settings > Display only shows a single monitor graphic with the text label "1|2" in the default state. "Detect other display" does nothing, and there's no hint about how to extend to a realized second display. Only after you do Win+P > Extend does that Settings interface actually show two monitor graphics. (This was another road bump that blocked me from discovering it.)

Comment: Well, the Settings interface does have the same "Duplicate/Extend" menu a few rows below, although it's not immediately obvious.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar situation of needing to get presenter view in a classroom. If the computer isn't too locked down, the simplest solution is to connect a display via USB.

The most common technology used for this is called DisplayLink. It requires your IT department to [install the DisplayLink driver](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads) on the computer - depending on your IT department, this may be easy or may be impossible.

There are several different ways you can add one, but the easiest is a single-cable USB display - the same USB cable provides power and data to the display from the computer. Here is an example (NOT a recommendation, just to give you an idea of what it might look like): [https://www.amazon.com/AOC-I1659FWUX-USB-Powered-Portable-1920x1080/dp/B06X9C6XFK/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06X9C6XFK)

If you already have another monitor that you don't mind carrying around, you can get a DisplayLink HDMI adapter (or DVI, VGA adapter, if your monitor is older). It is probably much less expensive, and it works the same way except that you'll need a separate power cable for your monitor.

Comment: DisplayLink is a great option, and I think that modern Windows might even come with the drivers preloaded, or at least available through Windows Update, so you don't have to download and install anything yourself.  Whether or not this would work on a presumably locked down machine I can't say.

Comment: As of Windows 10, it is standard and part of Windows by default, so it worked out of the box with my wife's locked down computer from school. Test first though, because they can go out of their way to remove/disable the drivers if they feel like it. Definitely need to be installed on Windows 7.

Comment: This was the idea I'd come to post, too—I picked up one of these types of monitors (ASUS MB16AC, in my case) while working from home early in the pandemic, and it was surprising to me just how well it worked.

Comment: Don't those USB monitors all require USB 3 (or maybe even higher 3.x versions)? The lectern computer might be too old for that or those ports might not be exposed. OP also said they have no access to the monitor cables, which might mean they can't connect additional video cables, if the computer even has additional video ports available.

Comment: @gre_gor I have used USB 2.0 DisplayLink devices in the past - they do exist, they might just be a little harder to find now that USB 3+ is common.

Comment: Do DisplayLink devices made for USB 3.x require being connected to a 3.x port, or can they still function as 2.0 devices?

Comment: @u1686_grawity I've never had the occasion to test that, but it's a good question.

Answer (score 4):

Having worked in IT in education, you're quite a distance from the "regular" user level.  Academics come in all technical skill levels, which don't correlate with their talent nor their teaching ability.

Your question has two parts - How to get your classroom gear to work better for you, AND without messing up other users of the same equipment.

If you want to effect change across the whole organisation, then you'll need to get included in budget/planning for IT and have a Proof of Concept.  Only once the merits of the new-way are seen will anyone understand what your goal is.

If you had your own teaching room then it would be much easier, but sharing the space with others makes it hard.

- From the college's point of view, the easiest solution is a complete duplication of gear that you bring in and set up as needed.  This allows other room users to work with the setup they know.  Downside is the cost of additional equipment, and the setup/knockdown time along with wear and tear on moving it all.
  If you could access the cable that goes from the lectern up to the projector, and move it to your own laptop then that could be sufficient.  Just remember to return it to original when you finish.

People can be resistant to change - if they see the New Setup as having to rework all their slides, then it brings a negative reaction.   Instead - you need to show the positive benefits to them.

In a perfect solution, this could be done during a hardware refresh, providing new functionality with a keypress but defaulting to the old duplication setup.

Comment: Another education IT worker here... years back we used to have manual audio/video selectors between the room PC and a DVD/VHS player. The largest instructor complaint in the rooms was when one instructor used the DVD player, the next person in the room often lacked the technical ability to identify what had happened and just set the dial back to the position labeled "computer", and would instead open a ticket.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to install software on the machine, another option is [Spacedesk](https://www.spacedesk.net/), which allows you to use another device as an external monitor over the LAN or USB.

There are client apps for Windows, iOS, and Android, so if you already have a tablet, you can use it as a pretty good monitor.